# Didn't get the run terminal in mingw

Tags: windows-7, mingw, mingw64

I've installed mingw from [mingw](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/)

While installing I stopped in mingw installation manager. I followed this tutorial :
[tutorial](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Epattis/common/handouts/mingweclipse/mingw.html)

In the Installation manager :
[image]

Then I reviewed those changes :

[image]

Then I clicked close. After that I didn't get any downloads as said in the tutorial.

Then I opened my control panel to edit the environment variable.

In the control panel :
[image]

After that I clicked ok.

After all these works, I still didn't get my **run terminal** in my windows 7 - 32 bit. Still I got only installation manager and shell. run terminal didn't appear

What to do next to get the run terminal???

[image]

Comment: Why are you installing mingw? It's not the easiest to use, and there are alternatives.

Comment: I need that for my studies @harrymc

Comment: What studies require mingw and nothing else?

Comment: I want to import C++ files in Python. In my text book only using mingw is given. That's why @harrymc

Comment: You are using a MinGW version dating from from 2013. There is a newer version on [MinGW.org](http://www.mingw.org/). If your Windows is 64-bit, look into [Mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php).

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 32 bit Os. And I'm sure that I installed the newest version. What else to be done? @harrymc

Comment: Does this post help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430944/i-cant-find-my-mingw-shell-after-installing-with-gui-installer

If you are able to find the so called bat file, create a shortcut for the same in the start menu folder you have shown above.

Answer (score 0):

For studies it is advised to use Code::Blocks IDE. Code Blocks uses MinGW as a compiler.
You will get the same binary as using MinGW but in a comfort way.

http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26